# Machine Learning algorithm selection with good accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

What ml algorithm can be used to predict the likelihood of a driver causing road accident?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common problem solved by the auto insurance industry. Usually you can run Generalized Linear Models (GLM) and many other traditional ML algorithms like Tree type models.

Answer (score 0):

**Attributes make large difference than Algorithm**

Before Jumping into algorithm its better to check the whole data and is there any possibility for dimensional reduction and any correlation between the attributes that provide the rest and try as much as possible to get perfect attributes that help to better prediction.

If you have a large data set Neural Network or Gradient Boosting has more probability to give more accuracy. if you have small data-set there is no much difference between any kind of algorithm.